# Android - app image is blank

Tags: android, icons, android-mipmap

I have created an `android app`. For past 1 month the `android app icon` that shows on menu of android mobile was fine, but don't know why the `app icon` shown on menu of the mobile is `black` (no icon was shown). The `app name` is being shown but `app icon` is not shown.

The below shown screen shots are my `Manifest file code` and `structure` of my `app icons in mipmap folder`.

[image: Code to get <code>appicon</code>]

[image: structure of mipmap]

Why was my `app icon` not visible ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try out following :

1) Check for your all icons are proper and same in all dimensions that is hdpi ,xhdpi etc.

2) Uninstall your app and then again install it

3) Change all your icons with some other icons and then check is it showing proper icon or issue is still there.